# Как создать фильтр по кастомной таксономии woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет! Сделал свою таксономию для товаров woocommerce и вот думаю как организовать фильтр по ней. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Например если фильтры пишутся все ручками, то +еще поле с таксономией и выборку через хук

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_function_name' );
function action_function_name( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && is_shop() && $query->is_main_query() && !empty(get_query_var('people'))  ){
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => get_query_var('people')
            )
        ) );
    }
}
```

Или попробовать плагин [WooCommerce Products Filter](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/)